The pocative case for adjectives and declensions
It's my understanding that for numbers, declensions follow the rules as such:
Single case:

1 of an item: nominative for both adjective and noun

Pocative case:

2-4 of an item for masculine and neuter: genitive plural for
adjective / genitive singular for noun
2-4 of an item for feminine: nominative plural for adjective /
genitive singular for noun

Plural case:

5-9 of an item: genitive plural for both adjective and noun

But I came across the following sentence when reading: "У меня есть три старших сестры"
It appears to be declined to genitive plural for the adjective and genitive singular for the noun.
But if the above rules are correct, wouldn't it be 2-4 of a feminine item, so "старшие сестры"
What am I missing here? Why isn't the adjective in nominative plural?
Also as a general point -- in conversation, are these rules usually followed or is this more for written text, whereas in speech it's not as formalized? For example, something more like Nominative singular for 1, Genitive Singular for 2-4 and genitive plural for 5+ for both adjectives and nouns when speaking? Does it sound incorrect when spoken?

Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! What exactly is "pocative case"? Did you mean "paucal"?

Also, does it answer your question: https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/27525/134?
